# Use Bonjour print services to allow OS X Mac to see Windows 7 VM IIS

Tags: macos, iis, virtual-machine, bonjour

I've been following this blog post, which claims to work to allow OS X to see IIS on my Windows VM (I'm using VMware Fusion):

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Expose-IISExpress-to-Mac-from-a-Windows-Virtual-Machine.aspx

I followed the blog points to the letter and can see IIS inside the VM in the browser fine, but not on OS X

Anyone got any idea what I might be missing config wise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the issue I was having was that my **network adapter** in VMware fusion was set to `NAT`.

It should be set to `Bridged`, so that the VM appears as a separate address to the mac.  Then the tutorial mentioned in the question works perfectly.

Hope this helps someone!